# If $f(x)=x^4+4x^3+26$, then find the number of solutions of $f(f(f(f(x))))=26$ is ____

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x)=x^4+4x^3+26$, then find the number of solutions of $f(f(f(f(x))))=26$ is ____

My approach is as follows:

$f'(x)=4x^3+12x^2=4x^2(x+3)$

$f''(x)=12x^2+24x=12x(x+2)$

At $x=-3$ it is minimum as the value of $f'(x)$ changes from negative to positive then $f(-3)=(-3)^4+4(-3)^3+26=-1$, therefore the range of $f(x)$ is $[-1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salam Walekum,

You're on the right path, this question can be best solved graphically, $f^{'}(x)$ = 0 has two roots -3 and 0. as $f(-3)$ = -1, the range is $[-1,\infty)$.

$f^{''}(-3)$ > 0, Implying $f(-3)$ is  $(local)$ $minimum$ of $f(x)$.

Now, Inflection of the graph can be checked using $f^{''}(x)$ = 0, So f(x) has two inflection points which are 0 and -2. Also f(0) is 26. this is enough to understand the graph.

To evaluate let $g(x) = f(f(f(f(x))))$, now lets label g(x) as $g(x) = f_4(f_3(f_2(f_1(x))))$, as $f_1(x)$ has range $[-1,\infty)$, f(-1) = 23 and $f(\infty)$ =  $\infty$ so that implies $f_2(f_1(x))$ has a range $[23,\infty)$ and so on. So,  $f(f(f(f(x))))$ > 26 implying  $f(f(f(f(x))))$ has zero solutions

Answer (score 1):

Clearly  $f(x) = 26 \iff x = 0$ or $x = -4$. Since the range of $f$ is $[-1,\infty)$ we now look for solutions to
$$f(x) = 0$$
We know that $f$ decreases for $x < -3$  and increases for $x>-3$ with a global minimum $f(-3) = -1.$ It follows that $f$ has exactly two roots (one on each side of $x = -3$). Since $f(-2) = 16 - 32 + 26 = 10$ it follows by the interemediate value theorem that both roots are on the intervall $(-\infty, -2$) which does not interesect the range of $f$.

Therefore the equation $(f\circ f \circ f \circ f)(x) = 26$ has no solutions.